# Loggin into Drupal using Yahoo mail

Tags: users

Merry Christmas to all,
I would like to allow users to log in my site using their Yahoo e-mail.
Is there a module for that?I am using Drupal 7.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [RPX (Janrain Engage)](http://drupal.org/project/rpx) module.

> Using Janrain Engage, Drupal sites can authenticate new and existing
>   users with popular social networks, map user profile data from these
>   websites to Drupal fields, and share Drupal content with a user's
>   friends on their social networks.
>
> This includes Facebook, Twitter, Google, Yahoo!, LinkedIn, Myspace,
>   AOL, PayPal, and Windows Live (see the complete list below).

Comment: Yeap,I know the Janrain module,but its not free after a number of users.Anyway,thanks fo the answer